# Enum comparison become False after reloading module

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have `MyEnum`, an enumerate derived from `enum`, defined in a `myenum.py` file such as :

```py
# myenum.py
import enum

class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
```

Then, I import this file using the `importlib.import_module()` method. I create `a` an instance of my enumerate, and test its value : it is correct, as intended.

However, if I reload my file, using `importlib.reload()`, `a` is no longer equal to `MyEnum.ONE`. What is causing this ? I'm on Python 3.7.

```py
# test.py
import importlib

def test_enum(e):
    print(e, myenum.MyEnum.ONE)
    print("test is :", e==myenum.MyEnum.ONE)

if __name__=='__main__':
    globals()["myenum"] = importlib.import_module("myenum")
    a = myenum.MyEnum.ONE
    test_enum(a)
    importlib.reload(globals()["myenum"])
    test_enum(a)
```

Result

```
MyEnum.ONE MyEnum.ONE
test is : True
MyEnum.ONE MyEnum.ONE
test is : False
```

Edit : After further research, it appears enums in Python are compared by IDs. However, when reimporting the module, the IDs of my enum are changed, which is why the comparison returns `False`.

What options would there be to avoid this ID change *or* allow the comparison to stay True ?

Comment: If your enum values are only going to be integers, then I would suggest using [IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum), which allows comparison by value instead of identity

Comment: @GeorgeD. noooo. That *defeats the entire purpose of enums*

Comment: Note, even if they *didn't* compare by id's since you've reloaded the module, you've effectively have two *seperate types*, and most types consider the type itself in equality comparisons, e.g. `if isinstance(other, Foo): return self.value == other.value else return NotImplemented`. So this is always going to be problematic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It's impossible to avoid the ID change; you made a new class with new instances *while instances of the existing class still existed*; definitionally, the IDs aren't *allowed* to be equal.
2. If you *must* allow them to compare equal despite differing identities, you can just override `__eq__` on the `enum` to do whatever you like, e.g.:

   ```
   class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
       ONE = 1
       TWO = 2
       def __eq__(self, other):
           if type(self).__qualname__ != type(other).__qualname__:
               return NotImplemented
           return self.name == other.name and self.value == other.value

       def __hash__(self):
           return hash((type(self).__qualname__, self.name))
   ```

   I don't recommend this (proper use of `enum`s will use `is` for comparisons, and nothing can make that work, since it relies on the IDs, which per point #1, will *always* differ), and it's going to be *much* slower (removing one of the benefits of `enum`s), but it's doable if you must allow `reload`ing during development. Just make sure to remove the `reload` for the production code.

Comment: Indeed, there is no clean way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot guarantee that `MyEnum` will always refer to the same class. But the instance `e` itself always refers the same class. Therefore, a workaround is to change your test to:

```
print("test is :", e==type(e).ONE)
```